# How to get private key from p12 in X509 certificate

Tags: ssl, swift3, ssl-certificate

I need to integrate my iOS app to consume a Web service requires a client certificate. I am using the below code to extract the private key from p12 in X509 certificate.
I found this code but not working, I translated it to swift 3.

```
func privateKeyFromCertificate() -> SecKeyRef {

    let certName : String = //name of the certificate//

    let resourcePath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(certName, ofType: "p12")!

    let p12Data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: resourcePath)!

    let key : NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
    let options : NSDictionary = [key : "password_for_certificate"]

    var privateKeyRef: SecKeyRef? = nil

    var items : CFArray?

    let securityError: OSStatus = SecPKCS12Import(p12Data, options, &items)

    //let description : CFString = CFCopyDescription(items)
    //print(description)

    let theArray : CFArray = items!

    if securityError == noErr && CFArrayGetCount(theArray) > 0 {
        let newArray = theArray as [AnyObject] as NSArray
        let dictionary = newArray.objectAtIndex(0)
        let secIdentity = dictionary.valueForKey(kSecImportItemIdentity as String) as! SecIdentityRef
        let securityError = SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(secIdentity , &privateKeyRef)
        if securityError != noErr {
            privateKeyRef = nil
        }
    }
    return privateKeyRef!
}
```

The error encounter at :
let secIdentity = dictionary.valueForKey(kSecImportItemIdentity as String) as! SecIdentityRef

**Below Updated version has the same problem at the same line:**

```
   func privateKeyFromCertificate() -> SecKey {       
        let certName : String = "certficateName"
        let resourcePath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: certName, ofType: "p12")!
        let p12Data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: resourcePath)!
        let key : NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
        let options : NSDictionary = [key : "password_for_certificate"]
        var privateKeyRef: SecKey? = nil
        var items : CFArray?
        let securityError: OSStatus = SecPKCS12Import(p12Data, options, &items)
        //let description : CFString = CFCopyDescription(items)
        //print(description)
        let theArray : CFArray = items!
        if securityError == noErr && CFArrayGetCount(theArray) > 0 {
            let newArray = theArray as [AnyObject] as NSArray
            let dictionary = newArray.object(at: 0)
//- encounter error here:
            let secIdentity = (dictionary as AnyObject).value(kSecImportItemIdentity as String) as! SecIdentity

            let securityError = SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(secIdentity , &privateKeyRef)
            if securityError != noErr {
                privateKeyRef = nil
            }
        }
        return privateKeyRef!
    }
```

I get the following error:

let secIdentity = (dictionary as AnyObject).value(kSecImportItemIdentity as String) as! SecIdentity

Cannot invoke 'Value' with any argument list of Type '(String)'

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Typo: `value` vs. `value(forKey:`? Btw: What is `CFArray as [AnyObject] as NSArray` for? And in case of an error your code will crash.

Comment: @vadian As you can see the old and new code for valueForKey, I am trying to get the private key. I am not sure what the CFArray does.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this for the error block - putting them in conditional id let block.

```
if let secIdentity = (dictionary as AnyObject).value(forKey: kSecImportItemIdentity as String) {
            let securityError = SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(secIdentity as! SecIdentity , &privateKeyRef)
            if securityError != noErr {
                privateKeyRef = nil
            }
        }
```